# z39.50 python 3.6 package

Tags: python-3.x, z39.50

Is there a Python 3.6 compatible Z39.50 stack?
I need to get XML-formatted MARC records from library databases that do not support SRU.

Comment: https://pypi.org/search/?q=Z39.50

Comment: Alternatively, I could use a stand-alone Linux client that can return an XML stream based on a Z39.50 search..